# Discover the original OS of a datafile from a oracle backup

Tags: oracle, restore, datafile

I have just been awarded with the task of recovering a oracle database with some given datafiles. However, nobody knows from which OS this backup comes from.

I have an AIX box to make the recover. Is there any way that i can determine the OS from the original datafiles?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mount the database and make a level 3 datafile header dump:

```
alter session set tracefile_identifier = 'header_dump';
alter session set events 'immediate trace name file_hdrs level 3';
```

In the trace file, you will find this section:

```
Platform Information:    Creation Platform ID: 13
Current Platform ID: 13 Last Platform ID: 13
```

The platform ID identifies the platform of the datafile, and that is all what matters.
You can match the platform ID to platform name by using the information in the [V$TRANSPORTABLE_PLATFORM](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/server.121/e17615/refrn30293.htm#REFRN30293) view. For example platform 13 is x86 Linux 64-bit:

```
SQL> select platform_name from v$transportable_platform where platform_id = 13;

PLATFORM_NAME
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
Linux x86 64-bit
```

Answer (score 0):

[Can some moderator please make this answer a comment to Balazs Papp`s answer?]

I'm not sure if the above solution works across different endianesses. I tried to copy a cold backup of a 64bit SPARC Database to a 64bit Linux x86 system and tried to verify the the answer but I keep getting errors

e.g. if I try to generate a new control file I keep on getting errors like

`ORA-27048: skgfifi: file header information is invalid`

a

`dbv --file d$DATAFILE`

gives a

`DBV-00107: Unknown header format (162) (2105310074)` error.

@Balazs Papp:
given the fact that you generally should use transportable tablespaces if you change your platform, can you please clarify 
if your solutions works across different endiannesses?